# trying to execute file compiled in C from PHP

Tags: php, c

I am trying to get a file I wrote in `C` to execute from a `PHP` script. It is not responding though I am not getting any errors at all. I can run the script from the command line just fine with `./serialTest Blah Blah` and the intended result is to take the command line arguments and output them to an LCD screen which works awesome from the command line.

To get it to run in `PHP` I am using `exec("./serialTest " . $inputField` the goal of this project is to take their input from a webpage in a text field and it will make it appear on the LCD screen and they can see what they typed via a live webcam feed.

The script is not executing do I have an error in my code or is this not possible? I would like to know if there is an alternative to this if it cant be done in this way. I realize there is probably some major security threat by allowing this but it is just a fun project on a home server for me and some friends.

Comment: you can't display the output in command prompt using `exec` command, it will display result in only webpage.

Comment: I realize that the script I wrote in C uses the Serial port to send the signal to a 2x16 LCD completely separate from the computer. I am not trying to `echo` it back into the webpage. The `C` script takes whatever command line arguments comes after `./serialTest` and will output it to the LCD.

Comment: If your script display the output in LCD screen then may be you haven't given proper filepath to execute the command. Try with giving full file path..

Comment: Besides @YogeshSuthar suggestion, look at exec return and parameters in the manual.

`string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )`

Comment: We need more info: what does your command require as parameters (a file? a string?) ? what is the code you use in PHP to exec? Do you require that execution should be killed on demand?

Comment: If I run the php file from the command line `php script.php` it works perfect I have changed the users and group to the same as every other file in the directory and also set the file to 777 but it still does not execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try:

```
exec("./serialTest   {$inputField}", $output, $status);
echo "status: " . $status;
echo "output: " . implode("\n", $output);
```

Comment: Can you give it a shot with the complete path of the binary.

Comment: To make thing's clearer, please try to run the changed commands?

Comment: what if `$inputFileId = '(rm *)';`? Have a look to [escapeshellarg](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

Comment: I tried the changed code and it said `status: 1 output:` but it still did not execute

Comment: OK I think I have found the problem I have been doing all my testing from command line as `root` I logged back in as `pi` the default user and it will not allow me to run `php script.php` it says `Unable to open serial device : Permission denied` So I know that is my issue but now I have to figure out how to get the command to run as `root`

Comment: you can use sudo to run as root. please setup sudo as passwordless to run it.

Answer (score 0):

If safe mode is enabled you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir.

Perhaps you should just change the C program's owner/group to php, apache, or the 'user' of the website files.

Comment: I tried the safe mode but I could not find it upon further reading of documentation it said it has been removed.