# Raspberry Pi unable to execute script by PHP

Tags: php, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm playing with [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) and anm Arduino [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) in order to run a script via [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server)/[PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). This script simple blink a [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode). I have already tested the script via shell and it works fine, with the command

```
/root/arduPi/blink_test
```

I'm able to see my LED blinking. So I made the same thing via Apache PHP with this short PHP script

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['cmd'])){
        echo '/root/arduPi/'.$_GET['cmd'];
        exec('/root/arduPi/'.$_GET['cmd']);
    }
?>
```

but nothing happen and no error has been displayed.

I tested the PHP code with

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

and it's fine. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Most likely because it's in the `root` folder and php/apache users don't have access to it.

Comment: You should try [RaspberryPi.Se]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while back it was because Apache does not have permission to access certain devices on the Pi. I fixed this by getting rid of the need to be root to access these devices. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127462/trying-to-execute-file-compiled-in-c-from-php) Is my post about this same issue the fix was to setup sudo as passwordless.
[THIS](https://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux) is what I used to accomplish setting up sudo as passwordless. You should then be able to execute the script as follows `exec('sudo /root/arduPi/'.$_GET['cmd']);`